# How to locate a data in sql database using column?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to select all data in a specific column in sql.

```
    self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
    self.res = self.cur.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

To select every item in the column

```
self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name")
self.res = self.cur.fetchall()
```

To select a particular item based on a condition

```
self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name = condition ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlite3_conn = sqlite3.connect(Config.sqlite_location)
sqlite3_cursor = sqlite3_conn.cursor()
record= sqlite3_conn.execute('SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id ')
for (column1_in_table,column2_in_table,.......) in record:
   print(column1_in_table)
```

just list your all column in for() statement that exist in table